# Export NUMBER from SQLDeveloper - comma instead of dot

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table with NUMBER(10,2) column (Oracle 11g). 
Lets say the sample value is 123.34
When I export the data I get '123,24'. Finally my INSERT script gives an error trying to insert VARCHAR value into NUMBER column.

I  have set Preferences/Database/NLS/Decimal Separator to . (dot)

How make SQLDeveloper use dot instead of comma while exporting NUMBER columns?

Answer (score 7):

I've found it. All Export preferences are in: Preferences/Database/Utilities/Delimiter Format/Delimiter

If it doesn't work add

```
AddVMOption -Duser.region=US
```

in sqldeveloper.conf

Comment: The delimiter option does not appear to work, however, the sqldeveloper.conf modification does.

Comment: @SjoerdvanLeent, Since the `Delimeter` option in the Preferences is the separator between the fields, not the delimiter of the integer and fractional parts of the number

Comment: @LeffBA, that was my finding as well, this was however the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Look for *Decimal Separator* under <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Database</kbd> > <kbd>NLS</kbd> > *Decimal Separator*:

[image: Decimal Separator]

Also, you can use:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '. ' ;
```

...on your SQL Developer session.

https://datacadamia.com/db/oracle/nls_numeric_characters